# Does Ubuntu support a CA chain?

Tags: ssl, certificates, tls

Is there a way to install a CA certificate where the file is a certificate chain?

I don't want to have certain files for each step so I want to use a PEM file with a certification chain e.g.:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried this in the following steps:

1. Copy my CA file (with the chain) to `usr/local/share/ca-certificates`
2. Run `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`

But I get Warning:

```
rehash: warning: skipping ca.pem, it does not contain exactly one certificate or CLR
```

If I install on the same way each certificate in a single file it works.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. If you just need it for verification: you can just install the chain certificate like any root certificate and it will be automatically taken into account when trying to verify a certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have edited my post, is my case now better to understand? 
As you can see: I tried it with a chain file but it does not work. Did you have a idea what I do wrong?

Comment: As I said, just install the chain certificate like a root certificate (i.e. separate file) and it will be automatically picked up during verification.

Comment: I am newbe at this topic. Can you explain me what you mean with "like a root certificate"? What is the different between my installation and "like a root certificate" installation?

Comment: Instead of putting both certificates into a single file put each of these in its own file

Comment: there a little bit more than two (two was only the example) and I have to install it an more systems again over time. 

The Question was if there is possibility to take it together and NOT have different files. On Arch it works.